# php5-gd depends: php5-common (= 5.4.36-0+deb7u3) but 5.6.6+dfsg-2 is to be installed

Tags: debian-wheezy, php5-gd

I using Debian Wheezy, I have problem with package named php5-gd.
When I put "apt-get install php5-gd" then I have this error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-gd : Depends: phpapi-20100525
           Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.36-0+deb7u3) but 5.6.6+dfsg-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried add to /etc/apt/preferences.d/preferences this:
Package: php5-gd
Pin: release a=precise
Pin-Priority: 991
(I read somewhere that it will fix my problem)
And I use update, again install php5-gd and I have same error :(

Thanks

Edit:

> ```
> #~~~~~~Wheezy~~~~~~#
> deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
> deb-src http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
> deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
> deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
> deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free contrib
> deb-src http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free contrib
>
> #~~~~~~Backports_Wheezy~~~~~~#
> deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main
> ```

Comment: What repositories you are using in your Debian Wheezy system?

Comment: Did you pin some _other_ packages?

Comment: Tero Kilkanen, I edit my post. Michael Hampton, no, I don't think so